# Thor equivalent or similar scripting framework for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, bash, thor

Is there a Thor equivalent (ruby tool) or similar scripting framework for Javascript that could be used to build scripts?

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for something like nomnom. It provides really good support for parsing options, providing usage, etc.

https://github.com/harthur/nomnom

Also, there is commander.js which offers prompt support (passwords, etc.)

https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js

Answer (score 1):

http://howtonode.org/intro-to-jake is a rake-equivalent in Javascript, used by Node.js